# How to derive $L_t$ in $D_{t}=\exp\left(L_{t}-\frac{1}{2}\left\langle L,L\right\rangle_{t}\right)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Here comes from a proof in Le Gall's Book Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus:

> Let $D$ be a continuous local martingale taking positive values. There exists a unique continuous local martingale $L$ such that 
>   \begin{equation}
> D_{t}=\exp\left(L_{t}-\frac{1}{2}\left\langle L,L\right\rangle_{t}\right)=\mathcal{E}(L)_{t}.
> \end{equation}
>   Moreover, $L$ is given by the formula
>   \begin{equation}
> L_{t}=\log D_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{D_{s}}\text{d}D_{s}.
> \end{equation}

In the proof, we can apply Ito's formula to $\log D_{t}$, and we get
\begin{equation}
\log D_{t}=\log D_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\text{d}D_{s}}{D_{s}}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\text{d}\left\langle D,D\right\rangle_{s}}{D_{s}^{2}}=L_{t}-\frac{1}{2}\left\langle L,L\right\rangle_{t}
\end{equation}
My question is, how can we directly set $L_{t}=\log D_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\text{d}D_{s}}{D_{s}}$, and why $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\text{d}\left\langle D,D\right\rangle_{s}}{D_{s}^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\left\langle L,L\right\rangle_{t}$
Please show me the calculation,thanks!

Comment: Simply identify the martingale part and the part with finite quadratic variation in the LHS and the RHS of the identity $$\log D_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\text{d}D_{s}}{D_{s}}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\text{d}\left\langle D,D\right\rangle_{s}}{D_{s}^{2}}=L_{t}-\frac{1}{2}\left\langle L,L\right\rangle_{t}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just forgot the bracket adding the initial value in the bracket on both sides is still the same.